# how to clear the form after submit it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a website which was developed using `php` and it contains  contact form where users submit their data. Down below is the code for contact form

```
<div class="form">
    <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
    <div id="errormessage"></div>
    <form  name="contactusform"  id="innov-contact" action="./dbFiles/formSubmit.php" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm" >
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="websiteurl" id="websiteurl" placeholder="website url" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="messages" rows="3" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message">
            </textarea>
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <p style="-webkit-margin-collapse: discard;">Captcha: </p>
        <p><img src="image.php?captcha_text=<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>">  <input type="text" value="" name="my-captcha"></p>
        <div class="validation"></div>
        <div id ="ss" class="text-center" >
            <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" title="Send Message" >SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

After submitting the form I want to clear the fields and I tried the below code

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("innov-contact").reset();
    }
</script>
```

From the above when I try to save the form it refreshes the fields but it does not save in database and even I tried the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#innov-contact")[0].reset();
</script>
```

But it does not clear the form and even I tried the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output1', 
        clearForm: true // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    }; 
     // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#innov-contact').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

Please let me any other method to clear the form

Comment: `$("#innov-contact")[0].reset()` will definitely work. Either you're performing it at the wrong time in the DOM lifecycle, or there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

use this `$("#fname").val("");` it will clear the value in the 'fname' input field. Like this you can clear every field.

Comment: Now I have edited the code.. Please check whether the above info helps.

Comment: I tried to clear email field as you specifiesd `<script> $("#fname").val(""); </script> `but not working

Comment: <script> `$("#email").val("");` </script> it will clear the email field. You need to put the id of field in the selector. Try every field like this. `$("#field_id").val("");`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/reset-selector/) to reset the form with jQuery

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 input type reset in form and click after ajax request:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#innov-contact').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Ajax...
    $("#reset").click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactusform" id="innov-contact" action="./dbFiles/formSubmit.php" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="websiteurl" id="websiteurl" placeholder="website url" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="messages" rows="3" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message">
                     </textarea>
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <p style="-webkit-margin-collapse: discard;">Captcha: </p>
  <p><img src="image.php?captcha_text=<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>"> <input type="text" value="" name="my-captcha"></p>
  <div class="validation"></div>
  <div id="ss" class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" title="Send Message">SUBMIT</button>
  </div><input type="reset" id="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the jQuery Form Plugin [docs](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api).

```
$('#innov-contact').clearForm();
```

If you want to clear any specific fields.

```
$('#innov-contact #email').clearFields();
```

Comment: I tried to clear email field as you specifiesd `<script>
 $('#innov-contact #email').clearFields();
    </script>` but not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-control').val('');
```

This will clear all form fields with the class `form-control`.

Comment: I tried it as `<script>
$('.form-control').val('');
</script>` but not working